# Saving a file using preferences in Java

Tags: java, file, preferences

Hey I was given a task to write a .dat and .idx file and save it to a certain directory on my server, which I can do.

But now i am assigned the task of saving the file to the directory only using preferences and this I am unsure how to do.
here is what I have so far;

```
private static String url2;
public static void generateDataFiles() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Preferences sysRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
    Preferences prefs = sysRoot.node( "com/davranetworks/zebu" );
    url2 = prefs.get("dburl", "jdbc:hsqldb:E:\\eem");
    try {
        for(int days = 0; days < 3; days++) {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            new File(url2 + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "\\").mkdir();
            File fileNameDat = new File(url2 + "\\rubanData\\day\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + ".dat");
            File fileNameIdx = new File(url2 + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + ".idx");
        }
```

This method is much longer and i only added the parts deemed neccessary.

When I run this, i get this output;

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: jdbc:hsqldb:E:\Davra
>   Networks\RuBAN\database\eemdb\rubanData\day\06-11-2013\06-11-2013.dat
>   (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

In the database directory there is a sub directory called rubanData and in that there is another sub directory called day. This is where I want to create directories and save my files to.

But in the database directory there is some eemdb files and the preferences keeps pointing to the eemdb and I dont know how to change that.

Anyone have any help or advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run a simple test on my local machine, I have no working experience with Preferences in Java but here is how i made it work:

```
 public static void generateDataFiles() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Preferences sysRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
        Preferences prefs = sysRoot.node("ro");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        url2 = prefs.get("dburl", "D:\\stackoverflow");
        try {
            for (int days = 0; days < 3; days++) {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                File dir = new File(url2 + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "\\");
                dir.mkdir();
                System.out.println(dir.canExecute());
                System.out.println(url2 + "\\rubanData\\day\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + ".dat");
                boolean f = new File(url2 + "\\rubanData\\day\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + ".dat").createNewFile();
                File fileNameDat = new File(url2 + "\\rubanData\\day\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + ".dat");
                System.out.println(fileNameDat.canRead());
                File fileNameIdx = new File(url2 + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "\\" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + ".idx");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        generateDataFiles();
    }
```

And i made sure that the Preference for the sysRoot node of "ro" exists and it had a key under it with the name "dburl" and the value "D:\stackoverflow" - where i should have my dat files etc.

So in your case that preference is probably set as:

"E:\Davra Networks\RuBAN\database\eemdb\" and your default value is "jdbc:hsqldb:E:\eem"

That is why you have the FileNotFoundException since you might actually be searching for the wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

The value *jdbc:hsqldb:* is not a valid path in the file system, it's a path for JDBC to find out stuff about your database. Supply a valid path in the file system and your code is likely gonna work.